# Holding Filter Parameter in Sessions Bad?

Tags: php, session

I have a page which displays a list of posts with pagination at the bottom and filtering parameters on the left. Whenever a user filters my posts, the page `$_POST`s and sets a session to hold these posted variables. Then whenever a user goes to the next page it uses the `$_SESSION`s to query my database with the parameters and then get the list of posts. After showing a friend this I was told it was a bad practice though I don't see why.

I'm not holding page results in these sessions but only the parameters to filter my query. He mentions that locked down browsers don't handle sessions well which may be true but this website isn't meant for them as it is also very javascript heavy.

My question is why would using Sessions in this instance be a bad idea or a bad practice?

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that you need to make sure the values stored in session are valid and sanitized. People have this notion that session variables are more secure when used for stuff like queries. However the data is only as secure as where it originated. If it was added to session directly from post, it is insecure.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn it does get sanitized.